# Adding a value to all indices except for one in a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

How can I add a value to all indices in numpy array `a` except one, **without** having to make a mask? Please note that I do **not** want to reverse the operation of the `a[0,0]` index, because in my use case, the operation on the right of the `+=`  cannot be performed at `0,0` index.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10, 10)

# The 0,0 index is incremented with 1.
a[0,0] += 1.

# I would like to increment all others with three += 3.
```

Comment: What's the problem with a mask?

Comment: Because that forces me to allocate a new array, and my use case is a very large array.

Comment: What is the problem with a basic loop? Then you won't use a new array.

Comment: @usr2564301. Performance.

Comment: Can you just iterate over rows/columns?

Comment: You may have to choose not the 'better' solution, but the least worse one ...

Comment: Why the downvote? Apparently the ranging in numpy does not have an elegant solution for this (yet).

Answer (score 2):

Just add 3 to the entire array and then subtract 2 from the chosen element:

```
a += 3
a[0, 0] -= 2
```

Comment: Of course my use case is much more complex, and the operation contains a computationally expensive computation that I want to avoid, or worse, which cannot compute, because it contains a division by the product of the two indices.

Comment: @Chiel Ah, might want to add that to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified it.

Answer (score 2):

This should also be possible with a `view()`, for example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(3, 3)

# The 0,0 index is incremented with 1.
a[0,0] += 1.

# I would like to increment all others with three += 3.
b = a.view()
b.shape = a.size
b[1:] += 3.
```

Results in:

```
In [12]: a
Out[12]: 
array([[ 1.06170829,  3.61834092,  3.24390753],
       [ 3.38696962,  3.5801084 ,  3.73288544],
       [ 3.67263889,  3.89885429,  3.3103394 ]])
```

There might be a shorter way of writing this, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), this method ensures that the data is not copied when doing the reshape (otherwise an error is thrown):

> It is not always possible to change the shape of an array without copying the data. If you want an error to be raised when the data is copied, you should assign the new shape to the shape attribute of the array

Comment: Or just ravel it : `a.ravel()[1:] +=3`

Comment: @B.M., nice, didn't know `ravel()` existed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
a[0,0] += 1
a[0,1:] += 3
a[1:,0] += 3
a[1:,1:] += 3
```

**Update:** Generalize to index(i, j):

```
a[i,j] += 1
a[:i,:] += 3
a[i+1:,:] += 3
a[i,:j] += 3
a[i,j+1:] += 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

add to all after the first row:

```
a[1:] += 1
```

add to all on first row except first element

```
a[0,1:] += 1
```

general i,j element

```
def add_to_all_except(i, j, array, value):

    array[:i] += value
    array[i + 1:] += value

    # add column-wise on
    array[i,:j] += value
    array[i,j+1:] += value
```